# Adcolony Android SDK: How to set userid for assigning rewards

Tags: android, sdk, adcolony

I am using Adcolony V4VC Demp App code in my App. I am not able to set UserId or UserEmail to send as a parameter in any function which is passed to the callback URL. Can anyone help me how to and where to specify UserId or UserName?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this

```
setDeviceID( id:String )
setCustomID( id:String )
getDeviceID() : String
getCustomID() : String
```

in your base class

Here is the link for ref https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Android-SDK/wiki/API-Details

Sets a custom ID String that is passed through to server-­side V4VC callbacks

```
static public void setCustomID( String id )
```

**Parameters**

- id
  The String identifier to use.

**Discussion**
The custom ID String is passed through as “&custom_id=...” and can be used at your discretion. *Must be called before AdColony.configure().*

Comment: Thanks for replying Suhail. Can u please tell me that do I have to use setCustomId immedialtely after calling "configure" method or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

On AdColony SDK 3.0.x the answer that suggests using `setCustomID` no longer works (the method does not exist on the SDK).
Instead, you need to do something like that:

```
AdColonyAppOptions adColonyAppOptions = new AdColonyAppOptions().setUserID(userId);

AdColony.configure(activity, adColonyAppOptions, AD_COLONY_APP_ID, AD_COLONY_ZONE_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set your user ID to AdColony, you will need to add “&custom_id=[CUSTOM_ID]” to the end your zone’s callback URL or it will not be provided to your server.

Then, in your server end script use:
$custom_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['custom_id']);

Note: &uid=[USER_ID] is not the custom uid and therefore you need to add &custom_id=[CUSTOM_ID] to the postback url.

Also don't forget to add the userid in your app end code,
in case of Android:

AdColonyAppOptions appOptions = AdColony.getAppOptions()
    .setUserID("newuserid");

/** Send new information to AdColony */

AdColony.setAppOptions(appOptions);

This way you won't get wrong values!